# How do I slow down the display AND transition time in Ken Burns Slideshow using this jquery code?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, transition

I've messed with the number values in the second "paragraph" of code. It doesn't seem to make a difference and I don't even recall the original settings. What numbers must be adjusted and what number value given to slow down the time that my image is displayed and it's fade transition effect?

```
(function($){

$.fn.kenburns = function(options) {

    var $canvas = $(this);
    var ctx = this[0].getContext('2d');
    var start_time = null;
    var width = $canvas.width();
    var height = $canvas.height();      

    var image_paths = options.images;       
    var display_time = options.display_time || 8000;
    var fade_time = Math.min(display_time / 8000, options.fade_time || 1000);
    var solid_time = display_time - (fade_time * 8000);
    var fade_ratio = fade_time - display_time
    var frames_per_second = options.frames_per_second || 30;        
    var frame_time = (1 / frames_per_second) * 1000;
    var zoom_level = 1 / (options.zoom || 2);
    var clear_color = options.background_color || '#000000';
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you've posted, it expects you to pass in `options.display_time` as the amount of time that each image is displayed.  You can adjust that parameter that you pass the `kenburns` method to change your slide timing faster or slower.

If you want to change the default time that a slide is displayed when no display time is passed in, you would change each occurrence of `8000` in the code to a different default time (that's the time in milliseconds), but it would make more sense to me to just pass in the desired time rather than editing this code.

Comment: First run through read greek to me. I am not good with jquery code. So...this is what I have to work with. I am understanding you to say that if I want more display time, change the "8000" in the options.display_time line.

You mentioned a second option, but I don't understand how I would go about doing it...as an adjunct to this script? within this script?

I'm lost. But the 000 being in milliseconds helps. so the higher the millisecond the longer the display time? I never made it very far in math...lol!

Comment: @user2150246 - Show me your code that calls the `kenburns` method (paste it into your original question) and I can show you what you should change there.

Comment: * Note: just changed the options.display_time to 100000 and it goes a touch slower, but the fade transition is clipped. Not sure which variable and what value to assign it to smooth out.

Comment: sorry...had to figure out how to display code. Follow this link: http://kaufmanphotography.com/kp-weddings/kenburns.js

Comment: @user2150246 - that isn't what I wanted.  I want YOUR code that uses the kenburns slideshow.  Somewhere you must have code that calls `$(selector).kenburns(...)`.  That's the code I need to see and that you should change.  Also, if you edit the actual kenburns code, then you have to change all occurrences of `8000` to some other value.  If you only change some, then you get clipping or worse.

Comment: Think this is it...php file I saved as a text file:

http://kaufmanphotography.com/kp-weddings/template-slider-kenburns-php.txt

Comment: Thank you for directing me to that file. I would never have thought to look for it. I changed second variable to "2000 and the speed is perfect. But how do I go back and make the fade a bit slower. It's too abrupt now.

Comment: @user2150246 - you probably need to put `http://kaufmanphotography.com/kp-weddings/kenburns.js` back the way it was before you edited it.

Comment: Nevermind!!! I went back to that original.js script and put the variables back to their original values and it all works smoothly. Thank you!!!

Comment: @user2150246 - do you know how StackOverflow is supposed to work where, if you get a helpful answer, you click the green checkmark to the left of it to indicate that it answered your question?  This indicates to the community that you got an answer, rewards the answerer for helping and provides you some reputation points for following the proper procedure.